# Command line option --log-level=INFO being ignored by pyinstaller

Tags: python, pyinstaller

I'm trying to build a executable with `pyinstaller` and set the log level at the build time, but the program appears to ignore the argument `--log-level=DEBUG`

This is my script `test.py`:

```
import logging
def run():
    logging.info('TEST INFO')
    logging.debug('TEST DEBUG')
    logging.warning('TEST WARNING')
    logging.critical('TEST CRITICAL')

    print 'TEST PRINT'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run()
```

And so I build the executable:

```
pyinstaller --log-level=DEBUG --onefile --clean test.py
```

If I run the binary, it only prints the warning and critical messages on the console, ignoring info and debug, regardless of the option --log-level:

```
$ dist/test 
WARNING:root:TEST WARNING
CRITICAL:root:TEST CRITICAL
TEST PRINT
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Python 2.7.6 and pyinstaller 3.0 on Ubuntu 14.04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [PyIntaller documentation](http://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#options) `----log-level=LOGLEVEL` defines "Amount of detail in **build-time console messages**". So this option does not set log level of your built application `dist/test` but only makes PyInstaller more/less verbose.